# Dataflow diagram designer in Silverlight

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, dataflow-diagram

I am looking for material for developing a simple dataflow designer in silverlight. For instance, how to define connectors, nodes, dragging nodes, etc. I already found useful information in [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) but please let me know if you know other useful resources for newbies (i.e. frameworks, events to capture, etc).